# Question on ssl handshake and behavior in java

Tags: java, security, apache, iis, ssl

I am using https to connect to an https server.
Specifically I am using apache httpclient and I configure the ssl context to use my keystore and truststore.
The https server I am using is IIS7 and is configured to **require** client authentication.
I think I have set it up properly.
Anyway, if I configure the httpClent's ssl context with a keystore (i.e. with client certificates) valid for IIS then there is no problem connecting.

**Now my problem is the following:** 
If I do **not** configure the ssl context with any client certificate to send to IIS, there is no connection with the server. What makes me think though, is the fact that I was expecting to see some java exception in the code as a result of a hanshake failure alert.
Monitoring what is happening with wireshark, I could not see a certificate request from IIS to my application, but I noticed that after ServerHelloDone everything was encrypted.
I did not expect that. I think the handshake is usually in cleartext.
I used private key to decrypt traces and i saw a certificate request from IIS but after many starting and opening of new connections.
My app send back as a response a certificate of length 0 and IIS replies with a TLSv1 **Finished**.
After that the packets stop (i.e. seems that the communication ends).
I was expecting a handshake alert.

**My question is**, is this how it is supposed to work or at least how IIS works?
Or if I do not see the alert something is wrong with my use case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was saying in [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131458/403-7-iis-7-5-ssl-client-certificate-authentication-issue/6140143#6140143), as far as I remember, IIS uses re-negotiation to get the client certificate. You should be able to change this behaviour using `netsh` and `clientcertnegotiate=enable` (depending on the version of IIS you're using).

You might also be interest in this [similar question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4039/ssl-handshake-failure-modes/4045#4045).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like IIS is only requiring client certificates for certain URLs (ie, for example.com/foo, but not example.com/bar).

In the initial handshake, it does not know which url you are requesting, so it does not require a certificate.  When it sees that you are requesting a restricted resource (/foo), it then rehandshakes, requiring a certificate.

However, I would still expect a handshake_failure to occur.

Comment: I think what you say makes sense concerning IIS.I am not sure what the TLSv1 Finished message is.It seems to be used to close the ssl connection instead of an alert

Comment: And the re-handshake, aka the renegotiation as in Bruno's answer below, is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Failing to supply a certificate in response to a CertificateRequest isn't an SSL protocol error, so there is no handshake_error. 'Requiring' instead of just 'needing' client certificates is added-in by SSL libraries, and all they can do if you don't send one is just close the connection.